# app neither installing not running on emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have created My First Android Hello World on Android Studio . but when I run it on emulator , it is not running neither installing it on Emulator .. Every time is only shows session '' Error only in log .. i have done restart several times . no use ,

this is my emulator Setting

[image: this is my emulator Setting]

My Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.administrator.facebooklogin" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I have changed the device and skins as well , but no use i have not found proper solution for session '' error .

Comment: what about the min API level you are using?

Comment: api -7 i am using  as minimum sdk

Comment: And do you get the option to select which device (ie either a real device or an emulator) to install?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have just started, Explore Genymotion, a faster and better alternative to Android virtual devices for Android Development.

Comment: u mean genymotion plugin on android studio ?